# Store, sort, and filter for multiple values in same column

Tags: microsoft-excel, database

I use an Excel table to manage a large database containing metadata of files along the following lines:

```
 Context     Activities         File         Folder
----------------------------------------------------------
 home        play, homework     filename1    folder/path/
 home        play, dinner       filename2    folder/path/
 school      test               filename3    folder/path/
 school      teaching           filename4    folder/path/
 playground  play, rest, talk   filename5    folder/path/
 fields      work, play, rest   filename6    folder/path/
```

Several columns ("Activity" in the example above) contain multiple values.  On the one hand, I'd like to be able to filter the database for specific values.
The sort/filter popup window displays all combinations of values in cells separately (such as "play, rest, talk", "work, play, rest", etc.).

Is there a way to treat them as separate values (comma-separated, or whatever-separated, I could change the comma to whatever character that would work)?

Eventually, I'd like to be able to filter them selecting all that contain "play", all that contain "play" AND "talk", all that contain "play" OR "talk", and things like "all that contain x, y, but not z," etc.

Does Excel have any way of doing this?

Comment: You *could* split the tags into multiple columns (text to columns), and/or use helper columns to determine the conditions you want. But it sounds like you need Access more than you need Excel.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I'm on a Mac, so unfortunately there's no Access. :(  As for splitting the columns that would blow up the database way too much, as there are multiple columns that should be able to hold multiple tags, and the number of tags varies greatly between one or two to up to 10 or more ...

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the `Context:Activities:File:Folder` cells, the goto > Data > filter.

Then click on the "Activities" filter button, > Text Filter.. > Custom Filter..

There you'll see the options set all the mentioned contain/deosNotContain/OR/AND case. (:

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm aware of this, but the maximum is two conditions with either AND or OR in between.  So for very basic things it works but not for anything more complex.   The individually checkboxes contain a list of all values of entire cells so ideally instead of making them display the entire cells I would like to make them display items of a list/named range, but I couldn't figure out how.